# Grid size doesn't bind to parent container's size

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to bind the size of a Grid to the size of the parent container (Relativepanel with size on auto, named 'MainPanel') in the XAML of a Page like this:

`<Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=MainPanel, Path=ActualWidth}">`

After doing so, it works in the Designer, but as soon as I run the App it shrinks again (and does so in the Designer).

I've also tried:

`<Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainPanel}">`

And removed all of my code interacting with the controls.

What is the problem here?
(Universal Windows App in VS 2019)

Comment: The `Grid` should fill its parent container by default. Try to remove `Width="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I saw this problem, it does not work within UWP platform, but works well in WPF platform. please refer [ActualHeightProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheightproperty?view=winrt-20348#remarks) remark part

> Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.

For your requirement, you could use Microsoft.Toolkit [FrameworkElement Extensions](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/09eb16132c13c2fadf98ae7e79fc754100330b4a/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/FrameworkElement/FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualSize.cs#L9) to make actual size binding avaiable.

Install `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` nuget, then set extension like the following

```
xmlns:ui="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI"
......
<RelativePanel
    x:Name="MainPanel"
    ui:FrameworkElementExtensions.EnableActualSizeBinding="True"
    SizeChanged="MainPanel_SizeChanged">
    <Grid
        Width="{Binding ElementName=MainPanel, Path=(ui:FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualWidth)}"
        Height="100"
        Background="SeaGreen" />
</RelativePanel>
```

For more detail please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions).

Answer (score 0):

ActualWidth is not a DependencyProperty and bindings see only first value of this property, which is 0 at the time when they are applied. You have to manually handle SizeChanged event with event handler or custom behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.sizechanged?view=winrt-19041